# Connecting Node Js Via React - IIS, HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, iis, https

I am trying to connect React JS app which is hosted in IIS with HTTPS, to node.js which is running in backend. Both are in same server.

React App Code. (Login.jsx)

```
if (validateForm()) {
  const { username, password } = values;
  let response = await fetch("https://domainname:9198/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }),
});
```

Node Js Code (index.mjs)

```
const port = 9198;
const app = express();
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const certificatePath = path.join('E:\\Folder\\SubFolder\\');
const options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certificatePath, 'temp.key')),
 cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certificatePath, 'temp.crt')),
};
const server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
console.log(`Server is listening on port 9198`);
 });
server.listen(9198, () => {
 console.log(`HTTPS server started on port 9198`);
});

app.use(express.json());
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const { username, password } = req.body;
const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM table_name where user_id= :username and password= :password`;
 ............
});
 } catch (err) {
  console.error("Error executing the query:", err);
}
```

Here the issues is, when i try to connect the login API, getting the below error in Chrome.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
asyncToGenerator.js:6     Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at Login.jsx:53:28
at u (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
at Generator.next (regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
at ft (asyncToGenerator.js:3:20)
at o (asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
at asyncToGenerator.js:27:7
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at asyncToGenerator.js:19:12
at Login.jsx:41:21
```

and the above error is pointing to this path.

```
let response = await fetch("https://domainname:9198/login", {
```

Tried the below things.

1. The Port is open.
2. Installed the Valid SSL Certificates, Keys etc.,
3. In Backend Node js is up and running.

Any idea, where i am doing wrong.?

Comment: Did you install IIS CORS module and configure it properly?

Comment: But as far as i checked, IIS Core is needed only when React and Node are hosted in different servers. Is that correct.? in my case, both are in same servers.

Comment: That's common misunderstanding of how CORS works.

Comment: Your above error shows CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT problem, have you tried setting time out in iis?

Comment: Yes. 60 Mins timeout is in IIS.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.